# What events are raised when a control is selected in the WPF design surface?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to build a WPF control inheriting from `Selector` and I want to change the state of the control when one of its items are selected in the design surface. Despite hooking on a debugger, I can't seem to capture any useful events from the control. I've managed to capture it being initialised and the wrappers for its child elements being initialised around the items of the selection, but I can't see any change of state, or event being triggered when the control is selected.

Importantly, I want to detect when the item is selected either by the user selecting the control in the design view or in the markup.

I'm trying to achieve a behaviour like that of the `TabControl`, where selecting a tab brings it to the front and exposes any content associated with the tab. I can't fathom how it works at design-time though.

What do I need to do to detect that a control is selected?